# How can I write my XSLT to repeat certain elements in my XML file?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to transform the following XML file:

```xml
<dataroot>
<Student>
<HUSID>idno</HUSID>
<SURNAME>Second Name</SURNAME>
<NUMHUS>idno2</NUMHUS>
<COURSEID>course1</COURSEID>
</Student>
<Student>
<HUSID>idno</HUSID>
<SURNAME>Surname</SURNAME>
<NUMHUS>idno2</NUMHUS>
<COURSEID>course2</COURSEID>
</Student>
<Student>
<HUSID>idno</HUSID>
<SURNAME>Surname</SURNAME>
<NUMHUS>idno2</NUMHUS>
<COURSEID>course3</COURSEID>
</Student>
</dataroot>
```

The following XSLT file is what I have been using to transform the above file:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="dataroot">
        <dataroot>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Student[not(HUSID = preceding-sibling::Student/HUSID)]" mode="student"/>
        </dataroot>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Student" mode="student">
        <xsl:variable name="husid" select="HUSID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="ownstu" select="OWNSTU"/>
        <xsl:variable name="birthdte" select="BIRTHDTE"/>
        <xsl:variable name="fnames" select="FNAMES"/>
        <xsl:variable name="surname" select="SURNAME"/>
        <xsl:variable name="ucasperid" select="UCASPERID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="uln" select="ULN"/>
        <xsl:variable name="numhus" select="NUMHUS"/>
        <Student>
            <HUSID>
                <xsl:value-of select="$husid"/>
            </HUSID>
            <SURNAME>
                <xsl:value-of select="$surname"/>
            </SURNAME>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/dataroot/Student[HUSID/text()=$husid]" mode="instanceperiod" />
        </Student>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Student" mode="instanceperiod">
        <xsl:variable name="courseid" select="COURSEID"/>
        <xsl:variable name="numhus" select="NUMHUS"/>
        <Instance>
            <NUMHUS>
                <xsl:value-of select="$numhus"/>
            </NUMHUS>
            <InstancePeriod>
                <COURSEID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$courseid"/>
                </COURSEID>
            </InstancePeriod>
        </Instance>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is:

```xml
<dataroot>
   <Student>
      <HUSID>idno</HUSID>
      <SURNAME>Second Name</SURNAME>
      <Instance>
         <NUMHUS>idno2</NUMHUS>
         <InstancePeriod>
            <COURSEID>course1</COURSEID>
         </InstancePeriod>
      </Instance>
      <Instance>
         <NUMHUS>idno2</NUMHUS>
         <InstancePeriod>
            <COURSEID>course2</COURSEID>
         </InstancePeriod>
      </Instance>
      <Instance>
         <NUMHUS>idno2</NUMHUS>
         <InstancePeriod>
            <COURSEID>course3</COURSEID>
         </InstancePeriod>
      </Instance>
   </Student>
</dataroot>
```

However, the output I want is as follows:

```xml
<dataroot>
   <Student>
      <HUSID>idno</HUSID>
      <SURNAME>Second Name</SURNAME>
      <Instance>
         <NUMHUS>idno2</NUMHUS>
         <InstancePeriod>
            <COURSEID>course1</COURSEID>
            <COURSEID>course2</COURSEID>
            <COURSEID>course3</COURSEID>
         </InstancePeriod>
      </Instance>
   </Student>
</dataroot>
```

I seem to be unable to produce this, or how to edit my XSLT file to create this result. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The logic that's required here is not clear. It seems like you want to group Students by their HUSID - but your example is confusing because you have Students with the same HUSID but a different SURNAME. In any case, if I am correct, you should start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure that I got your logic right, but this transformation gives your required output.
(In a real-world application I would have used a key for the lookup, but for simplicity I left it as a simple select.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="NUMHUS">
    <xsl:variable name="husid" select="../HUSID"/>
    <Instance>
      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </Instance>
    <InstancePeriod>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Student[HUSID=$husid]/COURSEID" mode="courseidmatch"/>
    </InstancePeriod>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="COURSEID" mode="courseidmatch">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="COURSEID"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qC98TB

Comment: Dude that's awesome thank you so much. My only question is how I make this apply only once? Your XSLT produces three different records for 'Student', but I am trying to create only one

Comment: Your input contains 3 students. Which one do you want to keep?